# Regular expression for length only - any characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to regex the contents of a textarea to be between 4 and 138 characters.

My regular expression is this:  `'/^.{4,138}$/'`

But - I want the user to be able to include return characters, which I believe the "." keeps them from doing.  Thoughts on what I need to change?

**EDIT :**

Obviously there are other ways to get the length of text - `strlen`...etc, but I'm looking for regex specifically due to the nature of the check (ie a plugin that requires regex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want the user to be able to include return characters, which I believe the "." keeps them from doing. Thoughts on what I need to change?

Either:

- change the `.` to `[\s\S]` *(whitespace/newlines are part of `\s`, all the rest is part of `\S`)*
- use the SINGLE_LINE (a.k.a DOTALL) [regex flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `/…/s`

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just check the string length using [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)? It would be much more efficient than doing a regex. Plus, you can give meaningful error messages.

```
$length = strlen($input);

if ($length > 138)
   print 'string too long';
else if ($length < 4)
   print 'string too short';
```

Comment: It's code created via a plugin - by changing it to non-regex, I'd have to rewirte the plugin.

Comment: (My question was not "how to find the length of a string in PHP" - it specifically asked for a regular expression.)

Comment: @Dave: As this comes up very often on SO, the answer was to be expected. Many tend to get lost in the possibilities of regex and try to solve *anything* with it, regularly grounding them is necessary.

Comment: @Tomalak - Guess I just hoped people would answer the actual question instead of assuming they knew the what I needed more than I did.  Still unsure why it's getting upvotes - it doesn't answer my question at all.  I'm in the process of trying your answer atm.

Comment: @Daniel - Their validations all require regex, so - there's no reason they would alter that just in case someone wanted to mess w/ it to make a non regex check.

Comment: @Dave: It is generally a safe bet to assume that the OP does not really ask what he wants, but what he think he wants. Alternative answers in the "why don't you just"-style aren't such a bad thing. After all, you didn't state that regex was your only option in the question.

Comment: ASP.NET has something similar to this with validators. You can write a CustomValidator to check string length, but it's easier and shorter to just use a RegularExpressionValidator with a similar regex. I agree with @Tomalak that it's a valid point, though; "why don't you just..."-type answers can be helpful and worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

Either

```
/^.{4,138}$/s
```

or

```
/^[\s\S]{4,138}$/
```

will match newlines.

The `s` flag tells the engine to treat the whole thing as a single line, so `.` will match `\n` in addition to what it usually matches. Note that this also causes `^` and `$` to match at the beginning and end of the *entire string* (rather than just the beginning/end of each *line*) unless you also use the `m` flag.

**[Here's some more info on regex flags.](http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/RZ/software/perl/manual/pod/perlre.html#DESCRIPTION)**

Answer (score 1):

Try `'/^.{%d,%d}$/s'` to have `.` match newlines as well.